# How is it possible to use the spacy[transformers] model in the transfomers pipeline?

Tags: python, spacy, huggingface-transformers, spacy-transformers

After training a `distilbert-base-uncased` with `spacy[transformers]` on a custom NER task, I would like to use the model in the `transformers pipeline`.

After training, for example, no `config.json` file is stored.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "transformers pipeline", but maybe you want to source the component? https://spacy.io/usage/processing-pipelines#sourced-components

Comment: Sorry for being a little unclear here. I would like to use this pipeline (https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/main_classes/pipelines).

Answer (score 1):

From what I'm hearing, you fine-tuned a transformer on a specific task using spaCy 3.0+ and would like to use it in the HuggingFace transformers pipeline ?

I crafted the best solution I could. Mind you, my solution isn't perfect. The spaCy model doesn't have a position embedding tensor that the Hugging Face model expects. And the Hugging Face model has a pooler layer that the spaCy model does not have. To fix this, I had to exclude the pooler layer and craftily add a position embedding tensor into the hf output. As a result, c/s scores will be lower. And not to mention the headache of converting the tokenizer.

```
from spacy.lang.en import English
from spacy.pipeline import EntityRecognizer

# Load your saved spaCy model
import spacy
import os
import shutil

# Load your trained spaCy model
nlp = spacy.load("your-spacy-model")

# Name of your new hf model
output_dir = 'hf-model-output-dir'
os.makedirs(output_dir, exist_ok=True)

from transformers import PreTrainedTokenizerFast, RobertaTokenizerFast

# Convert spaCy tokenization to your model's standard tokenization (eg. wordpiece, bpe, etc.)

class CustomTokenizer(PreTrainedTokenizerFast):
    def __init__(self, spacy_tokenizer, backend_tokenizer, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(tokenizer_object=backend_tokenizer, *args, **kwargs)
        self.spacy_tokenizer = spacy_tokenizer
        self._backend_tokenizer = backend_tokenizer

    def _tokenize(self, text):
        return [token.text for token in self.spacy_tokenizer(text)]

    def __getattr__(self, name):
        return getattr(self._backend_tokenizer, name)

    @property
    def backend_tokenizer(self):
        return self._backend_tokenizer

    def save_pretrained(self, save_directory, legacy_format=True, filename_prefix=None, push_to_hub=False, **kwargs):
        self._backend_tokenizer.save_pretrained(save_directory, legacy_format=legacy_format, filename_prefix=filename_prefix, push_to_hub=push_to_hub, **kwargs)


# Instantiate the custom tokenizer with the spaCy tokenizer and a backend tokenizer

spacy_tokenizer = nlp.tokenizer
backend_tokenizer = RobertaTokenizerFast.from_pretrained("roberta-base")
custom_tokenizer = CustomTokenizer(spacy_tokenizer, backend_tokenizer)

# Save the tokenizer

custom_tokenizer.save_pretrained(output_dir)

# Save the model weights and configuration files
#nlp.config.to_disk(os.path.join(output_dir, 'config.json'))
import spacy
from transformers import AutoConfig
import json


# Get the label names from the named entity recognizer component
ner = nlp.get_pipe("ner")
label_names = ner.labels

# Create an AutoConfig object based on the spaCy model ... I finetuned a roberta-base model for NER, in my case ...
config = AutoConfig.from_pretrained('roberta-base', num_labels=len(label_names), id2label={i: label for i, label in enumerate(label_names)}, label2id={label: i for i, label in enumerate(label_names)})

# Save the configuration to disk in the Transformers-compatible format
config_dict = config.to_dict()
with open(os.path.join(output_dir, 'config.json'), 'w') as f:
    json.dump(config_dict, f)

nlp.vocab.to_disk(os.path.join(output_dir, 'vocab.txt'))
from transformers import RobertaForTokenClassification

# Create a Hugging Face model using the configuration object

hf_model = RobertaForTokenClassification.from_pretrained("roberta-base", config=config)

# Get the weights from the spaCy model and set the Hugging Face model weights
state_dict = {k.replace("roberta.", ""): v for k, v in nlp.get_pipe("transformer").model.transformer.named_parameters()}
state_dict["embeddings.position_ids"] = hf_model.roberta.embeddings.position_ids
state_dict = {k: v for k, v in state_dict.items() if not k.startswith("pooler.")}
hf_model.roberta.load_state_dict(state_dict)

# Finally, save the Hugging Face model to disk

hf_model.save_pretrained(output_dir)
```

Comment: For my own knowledge, if anyone can improve on this solution, please try!